# Selenium Pyhton: click on a label without ID (4.3.0)

Tags: python, selenium

Currently, I try to select a label by clicking on it but a problem the element has no ID:

```
<div class="cas__wayf-idp h5-like">
    <span class="space space--sm"></span>
    <input type="radio" name="selection" class="js-wayf-composant" id="idp-EDU" value="EDU" data-memorisable="true" checked="checked">
    <label for="idp-EDU" class="form__label">TEXT IN THE LABEL</label>
</div>
```

I see that there are plenty of other ways including the xpath with text. After many tries I got this result:

```
driver.find_element("xpath", "//*[text()='TEXT IN THE LABEL']").click()
```

And this error:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[text()='TEXT IN THE LABEL']' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contains` method to  select text node

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'TEXT IN THE LABEL')]").click()
```

#OR

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(),"TEXT IN THE LABEL")]'))).click()
```

#Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still have a problem my text has the character ' and it prevents the code from working but I think I found another way to do what I wanted. I will know for next time ;)